# Drag and Drop with Sencha Ext-JS 4 Charts?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I would like to move Sencha Ext-JS 4.2.1 chart elements (bar chart, scatter chart) using drag-and-drop in order to update the values in the underlying objects. There is a lot of documentation about DnD and a lot about charts, but nothing on how to combine the two. Also, the DnD documentation seems to be quite outdated.

Cheers,
Frank

Comment: Actually, I would also be interested to change the size of the chart elements. So that may give way towards a solution: The standard Sencha DnD functionality may not be sufficient, and we'd need to create some custom "handles" on the edges of the chart objects for different type of dnd activities.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a preliminary summary on the state of this question:

- On the Sencha forum the moderator answered that 
  "Currently there is no support for DnD in our charting system."
  (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?280279-Drag-and-Drop-with-Ext-JS-4-Charts&p=1024651#post1024651)
- Looking more deeply into Sencha drag-and-drop, I could see that it works well for forms, trees and other GUI elements, but that it is not really suitable for charts.
- Instead, there is a much easier solution using the mouseDown, mouseUp and mouseMove events of the chart's "surface" object. This is also interesting if there are non-standard DnD interactions such as moving vs. resizing. This way it is necessary to implement a DnD status engine yourself which is a lot of hassle, but it's a standard problem.

So we'll continue working along the last (custom DnD) path. I'll post an update once we've got the first results.